# c++ return if invalid input

Tags: c++

I have done up a program which requires the following:

1. prompts user input account no
2. prompts user input account type

   2. if account `type == a`, prompts some input and does a certain formula [if]
   3. if account `type == b`, prompts some input and does another formula [else if]
   4. if account type is wrong(not a or b), prompts error and return to 2 [else]
3. prompts user input to exit [do while]

   3. if `input == y`, exits
   4. if `input == n`, return to 1

at the moment I'm pretty stuck at 2.3.
it prompts the error and goes to 3 instead of returning to 2 to prompt user input.

where is the problem? the else?

Comment: The devil is in the details! Please show the actual code you have so far.

Comment: I would really like to suggest the `goto` statement :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a loop to keep asking for an account type if the type is wrong:

```
do
{
    //1
    do 
    {
        //2
        if (type =="a")
            //2.1
        else if(type=="b")
            //2.2
        else
            //2.3
    } 
    while (type != "a" and type != "b");
    //3
    if(input == "y")
        return;
}
while (input == "n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any actual code it is impossible to say what is wrong with your attempt. However something like this should work

```
// ...
string atype;
while(atype != "a" && atype != "b") {
  cin >> atype;
  if(atype == "a") {
    // 2.1
  } else if(atype == "b") {
    // 2.2
  } else {
    cout << "wrong input" << endl;
  }
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you should do a bit of work when each case happens and you'd like to avoid the "goto" (which you probably should), I'd suggest splitting the 1), 2) and 3) part up in three separate functions.

If the stuff you should do is really trivial, I'd suggest a solution similar to the one posted by sepp2k. However, I would adjust the while loop to a do-while loop (you shouldn't test the atype at the beginning of the loop because technically it is not initialised).